# How to get force.com site URL?

Tags: force.com-sites

I have created one site page.  I send a link to this page to some users in an email.  Currently, the site page is in a sandbox and I have hard coded this link in email.  This means when I move this to production, I'll need to update the hard-coded link in the email.  I'd like to avoid hard coding this link.  Is there a dynamic method to determine the URL for a site page?

Answer (score 4):

You can query on the `Site` object and construct the URL, for example, HTTPS:

```
Site site = [SELECT Subdomain, UrlPathPrefix FROM Site];
String url = 'https://' + site.Subdomain + '.secure.force.com/' + site.UrlPathPrefix;

System.debug(url);
/* https://myname.secure.force.com/mysite */
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could query the Site like that.

Comment: its good but i am not getting correct result.

Answer (score 3):

I would never hard code a value that changes per environment. As @PJC said, this isn't a consistently easy thing to do in Apex. I would suggest looking into [Custom Settings](http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/cs_about.htm). From the documentation:

> Custom settings are similar to custom objects and enable application
>   developers to create custom sets of data, as well as create and
>   associate custom data for an organization, profile, or specific user.
>   All custom settings data is exposed in the application cache, which
>   enables efficient access without the cost of repeated queries to the
>   database. This data can then be used by formula fields, validation
>   rules, Apex, and the SOAP API.

So, you can create a Custom Setting, let's call it Force_com_Site_Url__c and it has a URL field called Site_Url__c. To access that, it would be

```
Force_com_Site_Url__c siteSettings = Force_com_Site_Url__c.getInstance();
System.debug('This is the URL - ' + siteSettings.Site_Url__c);
```

This doesn't count against any database limits and all of this information is cached so it returns very quickly. It is meant to act like a property file in other programming environments.

Answer (score 0):

To give you a simple answer, you can't, however, with some tinkering you can get it to work, it's not clean though. Else I would recommend just editing your email template on your production environment.

Please check the following link, I asked a potential helpful question a few weeks ago:
[Get Site URL from apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7639/get-site-url-from-apex)