# Get all Community urls in Apex

Tags: apex, url, community

The title is pretty much self explanatory, but I wanted to know if there is a way by which I can access all Community urls provided I have proper permissions set.

I already looked at Network class but it is only for logged in user and one community.

SO suppose if I have 4 communities created -

1. www.comm1.com/comm1
2. www.comm2.com/comm2
3. www.comm3.com/comm3
4. www.comm4.com/comm4

I want to access all these 4 urls in normal apex.

Let me know for a way for same.

Thanks,

Ray

Comment: What (part) of the URL do you want to get ? Providing an example in your question may help. The UrlPathPrefix field can be queried from the Network sObject for all communities.

Comment: added oone edit, let me know if it helps

Comment: Related link please check. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7639/get-site-url-from-apex?fromEmail=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can soql query as:

```
SELECT Domain, DomainType FROM Domain

SELECT Name, UrlPathPrefix FROM Network
```

You will get the domain and then all communities and build your logic.

Comment: Hi Prakash, Can you please provide the link for where can i see the other fields for Network and Domain Objects

Comment: Hello Ajay, You need to use workbench or eclipse for see all fields of Network and Domain Objects