# Get check if a LWC is in a community

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, pagereference

I am building a LWC that uses the `pageReference` that is not available in Communities.

Is there a way to check what context you are in from the LWC, whether it's in a community, a record page, or something else?

Comment: There’s a way to [identify](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_object_context) at least if its on a record page or not.

Comment: You can call apex, and in apex you can call `URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();` to get the URL from where the request originated, then you can compare it with `https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88329/get-all-community-urls-in-apex to dertermine if you are in a community or not