# Retrieve Force.com registered domain

Tags: apex, force.com, query, metadata-api, custom-domain

I need to return this value:

[image]

Is there anyway to get the registered Force.com domain for a given org, with raw Apex code or Metadata API?

Comment: Clarification: The objective is to obtain the configured Force.com Sites domain (this is the domain that is set once via Setup / Develop / Sites, and cannot be changed). We want to know: a) if such a domain has been configured already, and b) if there's a Force.com Sites domain configured, its URL. And we want to do so, even if no Force.com Sites exist in the org. The ultimate objective is to do the following from a custom settings page: 1) Guide the user in the right direction if no domain has been set, and 2) create a Force.com site (we intend to use the Metadata API). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You just need `SOQL`/`SOSL` on the `Domain` [object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_domain.htm). Just to double check, I looked at a domain, saw a url of `instance.salesforce.com/0I4?parameters=values`, and ran:

```
system.debug(Id.valueOf('0I4000000000000').getSObjectType()); // yields Domain
```

The `Domain Name` column you have highlighted is represented by the `Domain` field, leading to a somewhat silly looking query:

```
SELECT Domain FROM Domain
```

[image: Query Results]

---

I have also found that with any `Site` records configured, you get one record in that list view that is *not a domain at all*, but a link to your `Site` tab. The url you land on if you follow the link will look like `instance.salesforce.com/0DM?parameters=values`. If you want the value of the "Domain Name" from that column, you have to **[get a bit more hack-y](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7639/get-site-url-from-apex/95856#95856)**. I modified the code posted there by [@mattandneil](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/320/matt-and-neil) just a bit to get the exact value:

```
Site site = [SELECT GuestUserId FROM Site WHERE UrlPathPrefix != null LIMIT 1];

String path = '/sites/servlet.SiteDebugMode';
PageReference pr = new PageReference(path);
pr.getParameters().put('sitedebugmode', 'x');
pr.getParameters().put('guid', site.GuestUserId);
String url = pr.getContent().toString().substringAfter('URL=').substringBefore(path);

system.debug(url.substringBetween('//', '/'));
```

I do not believe this behavior is supported, but it has worked for at least two years, and does so currently.

Comment: Great answer, but I'm not able to retrieve Domains with that SOQL. Do I need an special permission, I'm on a dev org.

Comment: @MiguelLattuada Are you able to run the query? Can you be more specific? I haven't been able to hunt down any permissions related to `Domain` after a bit of digging.

Comment: I'm not getting any error, It's just an empty result.

Comment: @MiguelLattuada See my updates.

Comment: I get an error while running this as a non-admin user

Answer (score 2):

you can store this in custom setting. Although if you still need this in that case you can take help from URL class

```
Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
```

or you can query Domain sObject

```
Select id,Domain from domain
```

Comment: I don't see what the base url has to do with it? Or why you deleted your answer!

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes I want to ask you that I have one custom domain in my org not released for user. When I run this query I get 0 count so not sure if this is the correct answer.

Comment: Ah yeah I had one with visibility issues as well, but it was `CreatedBy` someone else. Hmm...

Comment: @AdrianLarson I create another one but still don't get them in query.

Comment: It's surely the correct object. Not sure why visibility would be an issue.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks for quick POC not sure why they are not coming in my org.

Comment: @AdrianLarson This isn't working for me either. Running as a System Administrator, with Force.com sites enabled and the View System Configuration permission (of course, it's the default Sys Admin profile, but just to be clear). I have a Force.com Site created, and a domain set for the Force.com Sites, which is listed under My Domains. Now ... A query on the Site object returns the Force.com site, with a correct value on the SiteDomain field. A query on the Domain object returns no results. A query on the DomainSite object returns no results either. Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: @AntonioGrassi were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: @PhilB Nopes. The best we can do is getting the domain when a Force.com site already existed. But if there isn't a Force.com Site already configured, we haven't found a way to query whether a domain was set already, nor which is the domain.