# B2B Lightning - Retrieve store URL from Product Id

Tags: lightning, b2b-commerce, b2b

Is there a way to programmatically build or retrieve a Product's url on a storefront using its ID?

I do see that the ID is included in the final URL:

https://(domain).force.com/(community)/s/product/hamilton-beach-coffee-maker/01t4W00000B6tnjQAB

But I wonder if there is a safe / robust way to get this URL either in a Lightning component or Apex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey @slaughterize good day.

we had this instance on our project and would like to share how we constructed the URLs programmatically for consumption.

Think of it as 2 parts:

**BaseURL**: https://(domain).force.com/(community)/s

**Product detail page URL in your community**: /product/hamilton-beach-coffee-maker/01t4W00000B6tnjQAB

Now to get the BaseURL, luckily we can leverage **SiteDetail** object and get the **secureURL** which is explained by benahm in this StackExchange link:
[Get Site URL from apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7639/get-site-url-from-apex) and just append that secureUrl with **/s** string

All that is left is to construct the product detail page URL:

[image: Builder]

In my case the product detail page url is: */product/:recordName/:recordId*

1. **product** is the base url for the product detail page. if you want other base url name for this page you can customize this in the community builder
2. **recordName** becomes like a slug ([Some] Product) -> some-product
3. **recordId** of the entitled product

```
    // Assuming you have a method which returns the base url
    public static void retrieveStoreUrl() {
        Site mySite = [select Id from Site where Name = 'MySite'];
        SiteDetail mySiteDetail = [select SecureURL from SiteDetail where DurableId = :mySite.Id];
        return mySiteDetail.SecureUrl + '/s';
    }


    // We have a method which basically converts the string you passed to lowercase, removes any special character and replaces whitespaces with dash character
    // Example the product name is: [Some] Product Name
    // It will just convert the string to this value:  some-product-name
    public static void stringToSlug(String stringToConvert) {
        return stringToConvert.toLowerCase().trim().replaceAll('[^a-z0-9\\s]+', '').replaceAll('[\\s]+', '-');
    }

    // Now we begin constructing the url
    public static void returnProductUrl(Product2 entitledProduct) {
        String baseUrl = SomeClass.retrieveStoreUrl();

        // Convert the string to slug
        String productSlug = SomeUtilityClass.stringToSlug(entitledProduct.Name);

        // All thats left is to concatenate all the required values
        return baseUrl + '/product/' + productSlug + '/' + entitledProduct.Id; // Returns (https://(domain).force.com/buy/s/product/some-product-name/01t6F000005DgTpQAK)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this answer. Very useful