# How to get Site Base Url in visualforce email template

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!If(relatedTo.Origin != 'Portal',true,false)}">
<a href="https://{!$Setup.Utility__c.Support_Site_Url__c}/Tracking?tw={!relatedTo.TrackingKey__c}">Tracker Link</a>
 </apex:outputPanel>
```

In the above, I'm getting the url from custom setting but I want to get url from domain.

I have tried `LEFT($Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_450, FIND(‘/services’,$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_450))`. It gives api and server that i don't want.

Comment: While I've not actually tried the approach mentioned in my answer, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring '22 release](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_domain_classes.htm&release=236&type=5) came up with few classes -  `System.Domain`, `System.DomainCreator` & `System.DomainParser` - which can be used to dynamically fetch the domains and construct URLs via apex. Specifically, take a look at the code samples & methods in [System.DomainCreator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_DomainCreator.htm%5D) class.

You should be able to use custom controllers in Visualforce Email templates as mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_with_apex.htm). In the custom controller, fetch the domain via aforementioned apex methods & then use it to construct the URL in Visualforce.

*As mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_api.htm), `{!$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL__xxx}` & `{!$Api.Partner_Server_URL__xxx}` will only fetch the Enterprise WSDL SOAP endpoint & Partner WSDL SOAP endpoint respectively. These cannot be used to fetch the various other domains hosted by Salesforce.*

Answer (score 0):

If this is for an Experience site, I wrote a VF component controller that worked across dev/staging/prod for a Customer Support site. Adapt as you see fit

```
public inherited sharing class ButtonComponentCtrl {

    public String siteDeveloperName {get; set;}

    /**
     * experienceCloudBaseUrl
     * reference: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/247372/2602
     * @return baseURL of an experience cloud site which is independent of org (PROD, QA2, dev, etc)
     */
    public String experienceCloudBaseUrl {
        get {
            if (experienceCloudBaseUrl == null) {
                Site[] sites = [SELECT Id FROM Site WHERE Name = :siteDeveloperName];
                if (!sites.isEmpty()) {
                    SiteDetail siteDetail = [SELECT SecureURL FROM SiteDetail WHERE DurableId = :sites[0].Id];
                    experienceCloudBaseUrl = siteDetail.SecureUrl+
                        (siteDetail.SecureUrl.endsWith('/')     // PROD behaves differently than test
                            ? 's'
                            : '/s')    ;
                }
            }
            return experienceCloudBaseUrl;
        }
        private set;
    }
}
```

and the component (basically, a button to add to VF emails that directed back to a site page)

```
<!--
 - Designed to support button images with dynamic links to experience cloud sites
    Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384022&type=1
 -->

<apex:component id="ExperienceCloudButton" controller="ButtonComponentCtrl" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="buttonContentAssetDevName" type="String" description="Content Asset developer name for the button image"/>
    <apex:attribute name="buttonWidth" type="String" description="CSS width for button"/>
    <apex:attribute name="experienceSiteApiName" type="String" assignTo="{!siteDeveloperName}" description="Site Api name used to get baseUrl independent of org"/>
    <apex:attribute name="orgBaseUrl" type="String" description="Org's BaseUrl"/>
    <apex:attribute name="pathToExperiencePage" type="String" description="Path (relative) to page including any params"/>

    <apex:outputLink value="{!experienceCloudBaseUrl}{!pathToExperiencePage}">
        <apex:image id="clickableButton"
                    width="{!buttonWidth}"
                    value="{!orgBaseUrl}/file-asset-public/{!buttonContentAssetDevName}?oid={!$Organization.Id}"  alt="clickableButton"/>
    </apex:outputLink>
</apex:component>
```